# Boto3: Unable to add permission/subscribe Lambda to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I am trying to use `boto3` to programmatically subscribe my lambda function to a sns topic. When I execute my script, I see the integration in the AWS Lambda Console but publishing to the SNS topic does not invoke the function.

I then created the integration between the SNS topic and Lambda function directly in the AWS console itself. The AWS Console adds an `Identifier` field with the sns arn as the value. Now, publishing to the topic invokes the function.

In my script,I have added permissions(`lambda_client.add_permission`) using the values:,

```
{'Action': 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
'FunctionName':'my_lambda',
'Principal': 'sns.amazonaws.com', 
'SourceArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:redacted_acct_no:my-topic', 
'StatementId': 'lambda-03a99f95-f490-4b9c-8bf8-20ee85fb2bff'}
```

I also do 
`sns_client.subscribe()` and have successfully subscribed the lambda function to the topic

For testing purposes, I created two integrations, to two different topics and I called `lambda_client.get_policy()` and the policies are identical(of course, the `StatementId`s are different.

I have a similar setup for `S3` which works.